# How to install flutter plugin in the dartpad?

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

Today my phone is broken and I should work in view of some flutter project. Now I'm using the dartpad but I need to install a plugin. How can I install plugin in the dartpad or using it in some way?

Answer (score -2):

you can use

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. Plugins are not supported in dartpad.